# How to make sure REXML::Formatters::Pretty uses \t instead of white-space for indentation

Tags: ruby, formatting, indentation, rexml

It seems to me that there's no way of making sure REXML::Formatters::Pretty can use \t instead of white-space for the indentation strategy in the XML Tree. The only thing I can do is to define how many white spaces are used per indentation level.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Why? `\t` is generally a short cut for x number of white space characters unless you are parsing `\t` couldn't you just set this to 2 or 4 (preference depending?)

Comment: Ah? On Windows all my Text Editors shows a clear difference between \t and white spaces. The thing is that I'm building an xml given one xml as input. Since I want to make a diff afterwards the fact that the indentation rules are different makes it a whole mess.

Comment: Maybe provide an example of what you are hoping to accomplish then. Text Editor tab is generally configurable number of white spaces to indent by but a true text file with `\t` characters is different and when opened in most editors the configured value for the `\t` character will be applied to those lines.

Comment: Also `nokogiri` will allow you to use a true `\t` character. Something like `Nokogiri::XML.parse(YOUR_XML).write_to(OUTPUT_LOCATION,indent_text: "\t", indent: 1)` should do it. [Docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#write_to-instance_method)

Comment: engineersmnky at least neither Notepad++, BeyondCompare and svndiff seems to make this on-the-fly translation you're referring to. I'm not really sure what sort of example you expect from me actually. What I want to accomplish is replace indentation rules by using the character \t instead of the white space character, what isn't clear to you here?

Comment: I am certainly hoping that you are not expressing any kind of undue attitude here since I am the only one trying to help you with this. I have made a suggestion in the comment but not having any code to work from (since you provided none) I will not post this as an answer. Please feel free to look at `nokogiri` as an XML parser/generator solution as it gives you the functionality you are requesting where as `REXML` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why `REXML` library does not provide you with this option since it could definitely support it internally but you can just roll your own formatter:

```
module REXML
   module Formatters
     class Prettier < Pretty
        attr_accessor :style
        def initialize(indentation = 2, indent_style =" ", ie_hack=false)
           @style = indent_style
           super(indentation,ie_hack)
        end
        protected  

        def write_element(node, output)
          output << style*@level
          output << "<#{node.expanded_name}"

          node.attributes.each_attribute do |attr|
            output << " "
            attr.write( output )
          end unless node.attributes.empty?

          if node.children.empty?
            if @ie_hack
              output << " "
            end
            output << "/"
          else
            output << ">"
            # If compact and all children are text, and if the formatted output
            # is less than the specified width, then try to print everything on
            # one line
            skip = false
            if compact
              if node.children.inject(true) {|s,c| s & c.kind_of?(Text)}
                string = ""
                old_level = @level
                @level = 0
                node.children.each { |child| write( child, string ) }
                @level = old_level
                if string.length < @width
                  output << string
                  skip = true
                end
              end
            end
            unless skip
              output << "\n"
              @level += @indentation
              node.children.each { |child|
                next if child.kind_of?(Text) and child.to_s.strip.length == 0
                write( child, output )
                output << "\n"
              }
              @level -= @indentation
              output << style*@level
            end
            output << "</#{node.expanded_name}"
          end
          output << ">"
        end

        def write_text( node, output )
          s = node.to_s()
          s.gsub!(/\s/,' ')
          s.squeeze!(" ")
          s = wrap(s, @width - @level)
          s = indent_text(s, @level, style, true)
          output << (style*@level + s)
        end

        def write_comment( node, output)
          output << style * @level
          Default.instance_method(:write_comment).bind(self).call(node,output)
        end

        def write_cdata( node, output)
          output << style * @level
          Default.instance_method(:write_cdata).bind(self).call(node,output)
        end
     end
   end
 end
```

Now you can specify your own indentation level and a indent style e.g.

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML
string = <<EOF
  <mydoc>
    <someelement attribute="nanoo">Text, text, text</someelement>
  </mydoc>
EOF
doc = Document.new string

f = Formatters::Prettier(2,"h")
f.write(doc,$stdout)
#<mydoc>
#hh<someelement attribute='nanoo'>
#hhhhText, text, text
#hh</someelement>
#</mydoc>
```

I used "h" to show how the indentation works as `\t` will not show up in `$stdout` but in you case this would be

```
f = Formatters::Prettier(1,"\t")
```

Comment: Works absolutely great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually I couldn't figure out why in your code but it seems to add two white spaces after the tabs when writing comments.... weird.

Comment: @tbop that is because it seems `Pretty` does that and the `super` call is causing this to happen. I have modified the above code but have not tested it yet should work by binding the method to `Default` instead.

Comment: @tbop tested works appropriately by binding to `Default` and skipping the `Pretty` version.